# Laravel 5 Changing Database name in controller

Tags: php, database, laravel, sqlsrv

ers. I need to change the database name into a specific controller. I already changed the database.php into this

```
'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'loal'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test1'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],
    'sqlsrv2' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'local'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test2'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],
```

My main DB is test1 and I need to change it into test2 db name in here :

```
 public function TransactionHistory(Request $request){

    Config::set('database.default','sqlsrv2');

    dd(DB::connection() );
}
```

But it only returns null and it is still reading test 1. Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to change the connection by using `DB::connection()` method:

```
$connection = DB::connection('sqlsrv2'); //this will create a database connection using sqlsrv2 in your config.
```

Now, you can use `$connection` to run the queries, etc.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#accessing-connections) :

Comment: hello @jaysingkar,  I tried your solution but still it is reading test1 :( 

`$connection = DB::connection('sqlsrv2'); dd($connection->getDatabaseName());`

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't pay attention to your config file. In your `sqlsrv2` config, `'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test2'),` change  `env('DB_DATABASE', 'test2') ` to test 2 or change the environment variable to use other than 'DB_DATABASE' as it will have the same database name in both of your connection

Comment: Yeap. I get it now. Thanks brother :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eluquent there is more elegant way [Database Connection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#defining-models)

1. Create enother config for second connection

`

```
   'connections' => array(

    # Our primary database connection
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host1',
        'database'  => 'database1',
        'username'  => 'user1',
        'password'  => 'pass1'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    # Our secondary database connection
    'mysql2' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host2',
        'database'  => 'database2',
        'username'  => 'user2',
        'password'  => 'pass2'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
);
```

`

2. Set connection in your Model:

`

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The connection name for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = 'connection-name';
}
```